# How do I list all commits without cloning a repository?

Tags: java, git, jgit

Given a remote location, I would like to list all commits of that repository without having to clone it, using [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/).

As far as I know, accessing commits is only possible by doing a [`RevWalk`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalk.html). To obtain an object of this class, you need an object of [`Repository`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Repository.html). Now I tried creating a new, empty repository locally like so:

```
Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(localDir).call();
```

... and adding a remote location afterwards like so:

```
git.remoteAdd()
    .setName("origin");
    .setUri(new URIish(remoteLocationStr));
    .call();
```

However, when I try to start the [`RevWalk`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalk.html), it is empty.

```
try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(git.getRepository())) {
    for( RevCommit commit : revWalk ) {
        //... nothing to iterate here
    }
}
```

I assume this is due to the fact that I never did a `clone`, `pull` or similar to actually update the local file system with the necessary information.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to clone the whole repository? Using `fetch` perhaps? (any tricks allowed)

**Use Case**

I need to sync cloud storage with the contents of a git repository. After having cloned and uploaded all files of the repository, it is deleted from the machine that performed the upload. Unless hooks are available, I periodically check whether the latest commit happened after my latest upload. If so, I re-clone the repository and upload again.

If there is an entirely different, better approach of achieving this please let me know.

Comment: execute git log

Comment: you cannot do this with git command line tool, it always works on the local repo. You need a "git server" (like *Hithub*, *stash*, *gerrit* or alike) that provide a web-API to list the commits (or have their own commit list page...).

Comment: To show the history of a Git repository you need to clone it first.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann That's very disappointing, thanks anyway. Do you know of any other way to mirror a repo to cloud storage (AWS S3)?

Comment: @DoubleM isn't *Github* sort  of a "cloud storrage"? You can pay there for a account with private repositories, but as you plan to put you repo on AWS you might not have any valuable "intelectual property" in there anyway...

Comment: There is an article describing how to push to an S3 storage: http://blog.spearce.org/2008/07/using-jgit-to-publish-on-amazon-s3.html

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Well yes, however I need to aggregate data from different version control systems (git, svn...) and also direct file uploads in one place. S3 is what I chose as generic cloud storage.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Thanks. This will still require me to clone to local and then push to S3 if the original repo is located outside S3 (which it always is). Anyway I appreciate your help, thanks again.